# Can a druid change into a different beast while in wild shape

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

The question is rather simple, but the answer is not explicitly stated in the rules... Or at least not that I could find.

Can a druid just switch shape by expanding a wild shape use while transformed?

Let's say my character is a druid of the circle of the moon, he is transformed into a bear and I'm down to 1 hp at the start of my turn. Can I expend one use of wild shape to turn into a dire wolf? If so:

- Am I using an action for it? Or is it a bonus action still?
- Is the dire wolf shape at full hp?
- If the bear had some temporary hit points provided by an ally, are those temporary hit points transferred to the new form?